# Take multiple pictures in capturesession with an interval?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to take 10 with an interval of about 1 second using the [camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).

I have the following `createCaptureSession` to successfully create 10 capture requests, but where do I add the interval?

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
      try {
        for (int i =0; i < 10;i++) {
          session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, null);
        }
       } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

     @Override
     public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
       System.out.println("ConfigurationFailed");
     }
   }, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using [Camare2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) example.
You have to modify `lockFocus()` function add something like this:

`try {
    Thread.sleep(CAPTURE_WAITING_TIME_MILISECOND);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

on `onImageAvailable` you need to call `takePicture()` if image count is not 10. or it is better to call it on `ImageSaver`'s callback.

The interval cannot be exact time. it may change depending on the processing time.

Hope it helps